# Android. Автоматическое преобразование drawable ресурсов

Tags: android, linux, unix, конвертация, drawable

Доброго времени суток коллеги!
Надоело каждый раз вручную конвертировать drawable ресурсы для разных разрешений. 
Подскажите, существуют ли для сего дела плагины для Android Studio или же другие средства  автоматической конвертации (под Unix)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел для себя решение, хоть плагин и устаревший и пришлось немного повозиться с его установкой под Android Studio 4, но свою работу выполняет хорошо.

Ссылка на плагин:

https://github.com/Vincent-Loi/android-drawable-importer-intellij-plugin

[image: scr1]

Инструкция по установке.

1. Скачиваем архив.
   Сlone or download -> Download ZIP
2. Распаковываем. Переименовываем корневую папку в android-drawable-importer
3. Копируем в папку plugins где стоит Android Studio.
4. Скачиваем еще один архив ( [here](https://gpskaihu.nz/ADI-hack/) на скриншоте )

[image: scr2]

5. Распаковываем папку ADI-hack и копируем ёё туда же в папку plugins.
6. Возможно придется перезапустить несколько раз Android Studio или ребутнуть пк.

Как пользоваться -  кликаем правой кнопкой мыши на папке res в проекте, выбираем
New -> прокручиваем в конец -> Batch Drawable Import -> Выбираем изображение для импорта (Если исходное изображение высокого разрешения советую выбирать
Source-resolution -> XXXHDPI как на скриншоте ниже

[image: scr3]

Возможно это решение кому-то пригодится.